# How to Calculate Sum of the integer or double values in CSV file using JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

How to Calculate Sum of the integer or double values in CSV file using JMeter. I have a CSV file with dataset and I want to calculate total value of the those data in CSV file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Qry.png)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible options is using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().sum { it -> it as double },)}
```

this expression will additionally store the calculated value into `${sum}` [JMeter Variable:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().sum { it -> it as double },sum)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)